# Using a ContentResolver to get data from a ContentProvider in my own application

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have one app with a `ContentProvider`:

```
    <provider android:name="ExampleProvider" 
              android:readPermission="example.contentprovider.READ"
              android:label="Example Content Provider"
              android:authorities="example.contentprovider.provider"
    />
```

and another app requests permission to access the provider:

```
<uses-permission android:name="example.contentprovider.READ" />
```

But when I run the second app, I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  818): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{example.contentresolver/example.contentresolver.ContentResolverActivity}:
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading example.contentprovider.ExampleProvider
uri content://example.contentprovider.provider/words from pid=818, uid=10045
requires example.contentprovider.READ, or grantUriPermission()
```

Why am I getting this error?

[View full SSCCE here.](https://github.com/codeguru42/android-examples/tree/master/ContentProviderExample)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the permission first in the app that creates the ContentProvider, then use it.

```
<permission android:name="example.contentprovider.READ"
    android:permissionGroup="..."
    android:label="@string/perm_read"
    android:description="@string/perm_read_summary"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
```

Comment: Do I need to add a <permission> tag to my app that creates the ContentProvider or to the one that *uses* the provider?

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the anwser to make it clear. Of course the app that creates the ContentProvider.

Comment: After revisiting the Android docs, I see that I missed that small detail. Thanks for updating yoru answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that android:exported = true;